# Assigning to a struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, assign

I'm trying to assign new User Input values into a struct in DevC++. But whenever it gets to the point when the user values are being assigned to the struct, the program crashes and Windows will say it stopped working.

Here's the struct:

```
struct users{
    string uCode;
    string lName;
    string fName;
    string mInit;
    char type;
    char gender;
} users_t[10];
```

And here's the function that performs the assignment:

```
void createAccount(){
    string newUCode;
    string newLName;
    string newFName;
    string newMInit;
    char newGender;
    char newType;
    system("CLS");
    showBordersMain();

    gotoxy(30, 6); cout << "<!-- ACCOUNT CREATION -->";
    gotoxy(20, 10); cout << "USER CODE         : ";
    cin >> newUCode;

    if (newUCode.length() > 5){
        gotoxy(20, 17); cout << "USER CODE MUST BE 5 CHARACTERS IN LENGTH.\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        createAccount();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < uCount - 1; i++){
        if (newUCode == users_t[i].uCode){
            gotoxy(20, 17); cout << "USER CODE ALREADY EXISTS!\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            createAccount();
        }
    }

    gotoxy(20, 11); cout << "LAST NAME         : ";
    gotoxy(20, 12); cout << "FIRST NAME        : ";
    gotoxy(20, 13); cout << "MIDDLE INITIAL    : ";
    gotoxy(20, 14); cout << "GENDER [M/F]      : ";
    gotoxy(20, 15); cout << "ACCOUNT TYPE [A/C]: ";


    gotoxy(40, 11); cin >> newLName;
    gotoxy(40, 12); cin >> newFName;
    gotoxy(40, 13); cin >> newMInit;
    gotoxy(40, 14); cin >> newGender;
    gotoxy(40, 15); cin >> newType;

    //Problem starts here
    users_t[uCount].uCode = newUCode;
    //Program crashes before it reaches this point
    users_t[uCount].lName = newLName;
    users_t[uCount].fName = newFName;
    users_t[uCount].mInit = newMInit;
    users_t[uCount].gender = newGender;
    users_t[uCount].type = newType;

    gotoxy(20, 17); cout << "NEW USER ADDED!\n";

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Another thing, I had gotoxy() defined, in case you're wondering, and I'm using Orwell's DevC++ 5.10.

Comment: Where is `uCount` defined?

Comment: *"I'm using Orwell's DevC++ 5.10"*... you poor poor thing

Comment: Since you're looping from `0` to `uCount-1`, I can only assume that `uCount` is `10`, making `users_t[uCount]` an out of bounds access.  Lots of guessing here, since the relevant portions of code are not included.

Comment: I removed the -1 from uCount, but it just made it worse. Now, it couldn't make it to cout << "LAST NAME: ";

Comment: Please post minimal example that represents the problem is self contained (compiles as posted).

Comment: Please don't take my comment as extremist or offensive... but is there any special reason for you to use DevC++? There are many IDE's out there that provide great interface, nice debuggers, etc. I will not advertise anyone specific here, but I sincerely suggest you to install another one. Many of them are also open source, and you can follow its development, bugfixes, etc.

Comment: Handling errors by calling the method again is a bad idea. ( If you do it this way, you should return immediately after the call, not execute the remaining code. ) Better to return an error and let the calling code start again at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that uCount is set to 10? If so the following line will most likely lead to a segmentation fault and crash your program

```
users_t[uCount].uCode = newUCode;
```

As users_t is an array of 10 elements, you can only access the ones between the indexes 0 and 9 included.